# Privileged scopes are not accessible from my own account

Tags: php, uber-api

First of all everything worked three days ago. But today I found that each call to https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/current gives me `{"message":"This endpoint requires at least one of the following scopes: all_trips_lite, request, all_trips","code":"unauthorized"}`

I'm testing with my PERSONAL ACCESS TOKEN and also I have checked ALL scopes from the list (check [this screen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rwgfb3o2p2vop97/Screenshot%202017-12-08%2014.40.15.png?dl=0))

I'm using this code:

```
$api_url = "https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/current";

//Manually generated in Dashboard
$access_token = ".........................";


$header[0] = "Accept-Language: en_US";
$header[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
$header[]  = "Authorization: Bearer {$access_token}";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 140 );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );
$strData = curl_exec($ch);
```

How I can test Requests endpoint with my own generated access token?

Answer (score 2):

Investigated the issue and this is indeed a bug, but only with the "TEST WITH A PERSONAL ACCESS TOKEN" tool on the Uber API developer dashboard (see screenshot):
[image]

A bug has been filed to fix this issue, but the workaround in the meantime is to auth your Uber developer account using the steps outlined in the guide here (instead of the easier dashboard tool): 
https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/authentication/user-access-token

I will follow up and edit this answer when the dashboard access token tool bug is fixed, hopefully sometime next week. Thanks!